# Is every formula of LΩ equivalent to a formula of L1 modulo T1?

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, model-theory

Q: Is every formula of $L_\Omega$ equivalent to a formula of $L_1$ modulo $T_1$?

The notation comes from the following question: [Is the following theory countably axiomatizable?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/257132/is-the-following-theory-countably-axiomatizable)

Edit: I mean $T_\Omega$.

Comment: Okay, it looks like $T_0 \not= T_1$ and $T_1 = T_2 = T_\Omega$.

Comment: In what sense is $T_0\not=T_1$, if $T_1=T_2$? (Note that in my original answer where I said that the hierarchy collapses immediately in a sense, my indexing was wrong: $T_0$ is already "essentially the same as" $T_1$, in a precise sense; and I've edited that.)

Comment: $\exists v\,\forall x\, x\in v$ is not true in all models of $T_0$ but it is in all models of $T_1$.

Answer (score 3):

Noah is correct that over the theory $T_1$, we don't know about the new constants. But meanwhile, over the final theory $T_\Omega$, or what I would call $T_{\omega_1}$, every formula in the  extended language is equivalent to a formula in the language of (class) set theory itself. You have added constants $c_\phi$ and axioms $\forall x\ (x\in c_\phi\iff \phi(x))$, where $\phi$ uses only earlier-mentioned constants. So by induction, any instance of $x\in c_\phi$ that appears in a formula can be systematically eliminated by this means, and so in fact we don't need any of these new constants.

So over your final theory, every formula is equivalant to an assertion in the second-order language of set theory.

Comment: +1. Note for the OP that we don't have to wait until $T_\Omega$ to see this for a given sentence - each sentence at level $\alpha$ is immediately seen to be "redundant" by $T_\alpha$.

Comment: Yes. But my main point is that they are all redundant all the way back to the original language. So the constants are not needed for any purpose---we could instead just assert the instances of comprehension.

Comment: Indeed. I just wanted to point out to the OP that nothing "special" happens at $T_\Omega$. (By the way, in my original answer I meant to say that, but I got my indexing messed up - I fixed it now.)

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not. There are formulas in $L_2$, for example, involving constant symbols in $L_2$ but not in $L_1$. $T_1$ has nothing to say about those constant symbols, so no formula involving such a constant symbol (in a nontrivial manner) can be $T_1$-equivalent to an $L_1$ formula.

The sense in which $T_2$ is "no more than" $T_1$ is [**interpretability**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(model_theory)) (and [conservativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_extension)) - any model of $T_1$ interprets an expansion of itself which is a model of $T_2$.